# Minimal diagonal intersections in a convex polygon

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polygons, combinatorial-geometry

[OEIS A006561](http://oeis.org/A006561) gives the number of intersection points in the diagonals of a regular polygon. There's a [paper by Poonen](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9508209v3.pdf). For 4 vertices to 12, the number of intersection points is:

$$1, 5, 13, 35, 49, 126, 161, 330, 301$$

That's not minimal.  Here are my best values:

$$1, 5, 13, 29, 49, 99, 157, 225, 301$$

$7$ -- $29$ -- Drop a vertex of a regular octagon.
$9$ -- $99$ --  (shown below)
$10$ -- $157$ -- Drop vertices 1,  4 of a regular dodecagon.
$11$ -- $225$ -- Drop a vertex of a regular dodecagon.

[image: 9 points with 99 diagonal intersections]

Can anyone improve on these values, or extend them?  EDIT: This is [OEIS A230281](http://oeis.org/A230281), which is so far known as $1, 5, 13, 29, 49$. Higher values are unknown. a(2m) is **not** achieved by the regular 2m-gon in the case of a(10).

EDIT: I've improved my result for 9 points.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A230281

Comment: They haven't gotten very far with [A230281](http://oeis.org/A230281), have they?  Ten points is not the regular decagon.  Not sure how they got a(9) might be 94.

Comment: Not sure either. By the way, I found http://mathoverflow.net/questions/212361/minimal-number-of-intersections-in-a-convex-n-gon